# Explanation of the Doctype Syntax

Tags: doctype

There are plenty of threads explaining what Doctype to choose, but I can't find any explaining the actual syntax. Take for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd ">
```

In particular:

- Can PUBLIC be replaced with other values and what does it mean?
- Why does the url need to be surrounded with quotes?
- What is the "-"?
- Why is the first string separated by two slashes rather than 1?
- Does the EN stand for English? If so, why do websites also use `lang=en`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question.  I never really thought twice about it.

I found http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/d/doctype.htm that explains each section in detail.

Answer (score 2):

While it does not answer all of your questions, but I think it's a good start.  Wikipedia is your friend.  ;)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration

p.s. For the double quote question being left out, I think the quotes are there in order to interpret the strings with whitespaces correctly

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the first string separated by two slashes rather than 1?

The [SGML syntax](http://elibrary.fultus.com/technical/index.jsp?topic=/com.fultus.freebsd.books/books/fdp-primer/sgml-primer-doctype-declaration.html) is `"Owner//Keyword Description//Language"`.

But in practice, it's irrelevant, as browsers don't actually use SGML parsers for HTML.  DOCTYPE is just a switch to decide between quirks mode and standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

Doctypes aren't limited to HTML pages. Doctypes are used to reference Document Type Definitions (DTD), which define the constraint on the structure of a XML document.

There are different types possible, OP's example follows a "public external DTD" format:

```
<!DOCTYPE root_element PUBLIC "DTD_name" "DTD_location">
```

where:

- `root_element`: is the root of the xml
- `DTD_name`: an identifier of the DTD, so that processors could use a local version of it rather than having to download it
- `DTD_location`: the location of the DTD in case it isn't locally available.

The `DTD_name` also has a defined format:

```
"prefix//owner_of_the_DTD//description_of_the_DTD//ISO 639_language_identifier"
```

where `prefix` is one of the following:

- `ISO`: The DTD is an ISO standard. All ISO standards are approved.
- `+`: The DTD is an approved non-ISO standard.
- `-`: The DTD is an unapproved non-ISO standard.

Source: http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/doctype_declaration.shtml